# Почему после публикации android приложения его нельзя найти в поиске google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Написал приложуху (первую), в статусе - "опубликовано", уже два дня висит. Но вбиваю название приложения - не находит. Если по ссылке зайти, то все норм. На форумах пишут, что процедура индексации идет у кого-то 2 часа, у кого-то два дня. У меня прошло 3 дня! Почему так?

Comment: у меня одно из приложений появилось в поиске только на 4-5 день.

Comment: Привыкай!) Гугл всё делает с задержкой в пару дней

Comment: У меня такая же проблема , уже второй день не могу найти приложение , но по ссылке находит ... (Рабочая версия всё норм) У вас уже находит ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Доступность и параметры видимости приложений](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=ru)

> Мы понимаем ваше беспокойство относительно доступности приложения в
>   Google Play. Чтобы все пользователи могли найти и скачать приложение,
>   необходимо опубликовать его рабочую версию. Если текущей является
>   альфа- или бета-версия, [создайте рабочую](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011).
>
> Напоминаем, что изменения, внесенные в Play Console, обычно появляются
>   в Google Play через несколько часов.

Если спустя 24 часа ваше приложение все ещё не отображается в Google Play, выберите один из предложенных ниже вариантов.

**...**

**Я не могу найти приложение по названию**

**...**

> В Google Play приложения можно искать по названию, разработчику и
>   описанию. Если в названиях брендов или приложений используются общие
>   слова, это может затруднить работу поисковой системы при уточнении
>   результатов поиска. Обратите внимание, что мы постоянно улучшаем
>   алгоритм присвоения рейтинга приложениям. При этом неизбежно
>   изменяются результаты по некоторым запросам. Мы внимательно
>   отслеживаем запросы, чтобы предоставлять пользователям наиболее точные
>   результаты.
>
> На отображение приложения в результатах поиска в Google Play Маркете
>   влияет целый ряд факторов.
>
> Ниже описаны параметры, на основе которых производится фильтрация.
>   Важную роль в этом процессе играют файл манифеста и особенности
>   устройства. Также фильтрация выполняется на основе страны, мобильного
>   оператора, наличия или отсутствия SIM-карты и других факторов.
>   Например, если в манифесте приложения требуются функции телефона, оно
>   не будет отображаться в Google Play на устройствах без
>   соответствующего модуля, то есть на большинстве планшетных ПК. То же
>   касается уровней API: если для работы приложения требуется уровень API
>   не ниже седьмого, оно не будет отображаться на устройствах с уровнем
>   API 6 или ниже. Кроме того, платные приложения доступны только
>   пользователям из этих стран.
>
> Чтобы найти свое приложение в Google Play Маркете, укажите прямой URL
>   в одном из следующих форматов:
>
> ```
> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=имя_пакета
> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.имя_домена.имя_приложения
> ```